# Drop Down list will not display more than 1000 records

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to use a dynamic list for a parameter in my Crystal (v11.5). For some reason It will not let me see beyond 1000 entries.

I have modified a few the registry keys in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Business Objects\Crystal Reports\DatabaseServer

set the:
BrowseTimeout to 0,
MaxNBrowseValues to 2000 and 
NRecordsThreshold to 2000

The list is stuck at 1000 records and that particular table has nearly 1600 records.

I can import the values into a static list but preferably I would the dynamic list as I wold have to import everytime a user creates a new record - which is often.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Create a new registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
```

Add `MaxRowsetRecords` `DWORD` Value with a specific value